# why there is a difference between below given output?

Tags: php

```
$y = 07;
echo 'Y: '.$y; // result is 7
$y = 08;
echo 'Y: '.$y; // result is 0
```

[view demo](http://codepad.org/unsH35zN)

***:EDIT:***

One more similar to that

```
$y = 013;
echo $y + 5; //this result in 16
```

I can not figure it out how its ans is 16? Can any one help?

Comment: Is there a reason you're prepending a 0 to your numbers?

Comment: @Brian Driscoll: no reason...I came across this issue by going through some php related quetions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Part 1**

The rules for parsing are explained in the [Integers Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

In PHP a number starting with a 0 is a assumed to be in Octal. Because 08 in Octal isn't valid  you are getting 0.

**Part 2**

The same issue is in play, 013 in Octal is 11 in Decimal and 11 + 5 = 16

Answer (score 0):

In php integer variable is taken Octal.

http://www.ascii.cl/conversion.htm

show This link useful for you.i think.